# python pyplot specify the density of the dashed grid in matplotlib.style file

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would ask if somebody know if is possible or not in the file .mplstyle defining the density of the dashed grid .. currently i'm using a class in order to prepare my plots, I would try the method to create a mplstyle file and use this like:
`plt.style.use(['mystyle', 'mystyle-vega'])`
I found almost all option .. but once that I didn't realize how to do is how can I specify the dases=(5,9) of the grid, I find just the way to setting the grid as ' -- '

**EDIT** 
Ok thank you very much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the grid via rcParameters you can use the `grid.linestyle` parameter. Set this to any value you want.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["axes.grid"] = True
plt.rcParams["grid.linestyle"] = (5,9)

plt.gca()
plt.show()
```

[image]

It's currently [not possible to use such tuples](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11797) in an external matplotlibrc file.